# How to align two separate menu links in navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Demo: https://www.bootply.com/FeTVydhGoT

I have created a navbar that collapses all the links except for Login link. I would like this login link to be seen on mobile devices as a separate element but the problem seems to be its improper alignment - the login text is few pixels below the rest of menu links. How could I align it properly? I tried using margin-top on login link but the result is never perfectly aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `navbar-nav` in addition to `nav`...

```
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="pull-right">
          <a href="#" id="login">Login</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Also, it looks like the floats (pull-left, pull-right, navbar-right, etc...) are being overused.